# Xamarin Forms iOS IsSpellCheckEnabled not working

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to DISABLE spell check for an Entry item. I set this to False in the XAML -- I also set it to false in the code behind when I observed this didn't work as expected on iOS.

Bottom line: It doesn't appear to work on iOS. When I enter something iOS thinks is incorrect, it corrects it.

Does anyone have any info that might help me?

UPDATE:

Here is what the code behind looks like:

```
myTxt.IsSpellCheckEnabled = false;
```

SOLUTION UPDATE (Thanks to Jason):
The following is also required...

```
myTxt.IsTextPredictionEnabled = false;
```

Comment: instead of *describing* what you're doing, show the **actual code**

Comment: @Jason Sorry. Good point. And well-worth a down vote. Here it is:  myTxt.IsSpellCheckEnabled = false;

Comment: do you also have IsTextPredictionEnabled set to false?

Comment: @Jason I do not. I will try that out. Thank you.

Comment: @Jason That did the trick! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be sure to set `IsTextPredictionEnabled = false` too